# css - change color of link in css

Tags: css, hyperlink, colors

i have http://jsfiddle.net/bgw34wqn/.  I'm trying to figure out how can i change the font color of Menu3 to red.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navL4test">
    <ul class="navL4test">
      <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Menu2</a></li>
      <li class="navL4test-select"><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have css specificity issues here, based on the jsfiddle. also, when you write css rules and have commas, you have to also keep carrying the class names. such as:

```
.foo a:link, .foo a:active { ... }
```

you can change the jsfilddle rule to this (remove the :link part):

```
.navL4test-select a, .navL4test-select a:active {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have...

[image]

with this code:

```
.navL4test-select a:link, a:active {color: red;}
```